# Deduce type for temporary in template

Tags: c++, generics

I am trying to make a generic selection sort function using templates.

What I have made is:

```
template<typename T>
    void nrsort(T &a,int size)
    {
        // Applying Selection Sort
        double temp; // This is the issue

        for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++)
        {
            double minimum=a[i];  //  This one too
            for (int j = i+1; j < size ; j++)
            {
                if(a[j]<minimum)
                {
                    temp=a[i];;
                    a[i]=a[j];
                    minimum=a[j];
                    a[j]=temp;
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

I want a generic template that may be able to sort integers, floating point numbers, characters, etc.

This above mentioned code works but the major problem is that I have hardcoded the `double temp;` and `double minimum` and conversion of data takes place everytime.

If I write my `main` method as follows:

```
int main()
{
    int values[]={4,3,6,1};




    nrsort(values,4);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++)
    {
        cout<<values[i]<<"\t";
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Then the type `T` deduced in the template is `int [4]` an array of four integers. Inside the function, all these are converted to double and the code works fine.

But my question is, Is there any way so that I don't have to hardcode it to `double` and use something like the generic type `T'.

Thanks.

Comment: Just use `T`?  I don't see the problem.

Comment: @Donnie For this call `nrsort(values, 4)`, `T` will be deduced to be `int[4]`, not `int`.

Comment: most containers have a `value_type` member you can use.  It would be: `T::Value_type temp;`

Comment: @dyp *facepalm*.  More coffee.

Comment: You could also do it how the STL does and use "iterators".

Comment: @NathanOliver, that doesn't seem to be working. That's because to use `::` , T must be a namespace or a class type. In my case, it is `int [4]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you fix the scope of `temp`, you can simply use [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto):

```
template<typename T>
    void nrsort(T &a,int size)
    {
        // Applying Selection Sort


        for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++)
        {
            auto minimum=a[i];  //  This one too
            for (int j = i+1; j < size ; j++)
            {
                if(a[j]<minimum)
                {
                    auto temp=a[i];;
                    a[i]=a[j];
                    minimum=a[j];
                    a[j]=temp;
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

It will automatically deduce the right type.

Comment: Wow. This works awesome. Now since I am a beginner, does using auto has any "serious" demerits or it is a normal thing to do?

Comment: The main downside is you can't use it prior to C++11, but it's perfectly normal in modern C++ code, but totally unnecessary here. You can just use `T`.

Comment: @AkshayArora It is a completely safe and normal thing to do, but it is relatively new (2011). [Here](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/) you can read what the head of the C++ standard committee says about it.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, Nope I can't just use `T`. `T` here is `int [4]` although the code requires it to be `int`.

Comment: @BaummitAugen, there too now :)

Comment: You can then use `typedef decltype(a[0]) S;` and then use S instead of auto (or `decltype(a[0])` directly but thats ugly).

Comment: @MikeVine You could, but why would you?

Answer (score 4):

Your function isn't as generic as it could be.  The STL-way to solve such a problem is to use *iterators*.  It will allow you to sort C-style arrays, `std::vector`s and anything else that provides a random access iterator.  Your function should take a pair of iterators like this:

```
template <typename IteratorT>
void
my_sort(IteratorT begin, IteratorT end);
```

Then, if you `#include <iterator>`, you can query the value type (ie what you get if you dereference a `IteratorT`) like so

```
using ValueT = typename std::iterator_traits<IteratorT>::value_type;
```

Now, `ValueT` is a type alias for your type.

You can provide a convenience wrapper function if you like:

```
#include <utility>  // for std::begin() and std::end()

template<typename ContainerT>
void
my_sort(ContainerT& container)
{
  using std::begin;
  using std::end;
  my_sort(begin(container), end(container));
}
```

There is one problem: These function templates will match all too eagerly, even if the iterators are not random access iterators.  You can use SFINAE trickery to enable your template only if `std::iterator_traits<IteratorT>::iterator_category` is `std::random_access_iterator_tag`.  Or you could provide an overload that copies the elements (or pointers / iterators to them) into a `std::vector`, sorts that, and then copies the elements back.  Sometimes, this is the best you can do.

Comment: or just change the name `IteratorT` to `RandomIt` to make the user aware that you accept only random iterators. This is how e.g. `std::sort` is implemented. Sorting stuff which doesn't accept random access is *really* inefficient, and should be avoided at all costs. Hopefully `Concepts` will be a part of the new C++17 standard, which will allow you to specify constraints more naturally than `enable_if` on template parameters.